# What is wrong in this code?

Tags: php, functions

These code is in functions.php

```
function fbCount(){
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $fb = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fb', true );
    return $fb;
}

function pinCount(){
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $pin = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pin', true );
    return $pin;
}

function suCount(){
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $su = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'su', true );
    return $su;
}
```

And these code is in single.php (I am using socialCount class)

```
require("shareCount/share_count.php");
$count = new shareCount;
$getCount = $count->get(get_the_permalink());


// Facebook Count
if(empty(fbCount()) || fbCount() < 2) {
    $fbCount = update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fb', $getCount->facebook);
    $fbCount = $getCount->facebook;
} else {
    $fbCount = fbCount();
}

// Pinterest Count
if(empty(pinCount()) || pinCount() < 2) {
    $pinCount = update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pin', $getCount->pinterest);
    $pinCount = $getCount->pinterest;
} else {
    $pinCount = pinCount();
}

// Stumbleupon Count
if(empty(suCount()) || suCount() < 2) {
    $suCount = update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'su', $getCount->stumbleupon);
    $suCount = $getCount->stumbleupon;
} else {
    $suCount = suCount();
}
```

This loop is turn always false. What is wrong?

Comment: > This loop is turn always false

There's no loop in your code, only a bunch of if clauses. So what exactly is not working?

Comment: if have custom field item, then show.
if haven't custom field then show with socialCount class and add post meta for second query showing in custom field.